# Set tag to button via prepareForSegue

Tags: swift, uitableview, segue

I have a `tableView`that passes data with `prepareForSegue`to a new ViewController when pressed. In that ViewController I have a button that I want to use the `tag` function on.
Is it possible to set `tag`via `prepareForSegue`?

If row 1 in table view is pressed, `destination.button.tag == 1`and if row 2 is pressed `destination.button.tag == 2` and so on

Comment: No,Its not possible directly!!. You need extra variable to store tag, and in viewDidLoad you can set that tag to your button

Comment: The `button` property of your `destination` has low chances to be already initialized. For instance, if it's a IBOutlet, it won't be. Instead use a `var buttonTag: Int`, `destination.buttonTag = tag`, and in `viewDidLoad()`, button.tag = buttonTag`.